# How I create the custom TextBox Control in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to implement the own custom TextBox control in Asp.Net(C#).
Please give me some idea and links.

Comment: Step ask a question that is more specific.

Comment: what do you mean?  you want to create a TextBox control from scratch (as a Custom Control)?  you have something you want to add to the existing TextBox control?

Comment: @statichippo:I want to create TextBox control from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A control is simply a class. Create your own class deriving from the TextBox class. Override methods. Handle events. Add properties.

And then ask a specific question, and you'll get specific answers. Do a search on this site and you'll find recommendations for books on control development.

You'll also find http://asp.net to be of use.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a TextBox control from scratch, you can just create a CustomControl (msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt27tfhy.aspx) that outputs a textbox:

```
<input type="text" />
```

Obviously you'll want to add properties like length and css styles.  For an existing control like a TextBox I can't really imagine why you wouldn't just inherit from TextBox to add the extra functionality you want though -- why reinvent the wheel?  But if that's what you want to do...